# How to assign the values in NSMutableArray in ios?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, variable-assignment

I am trying to assign some values in NSMutableArray like this:

```
NSMutableArray* user;
user=[webSharedManager loginWithTwitterWithEmail:userName username:userName first_name:name gender:@"" last_name:@"" name:name id:ids photo:profileImage];
```

but its returning null, am i doing it wrong? if yes then please guide me the proper way. thanks in advance.

Comment: user is NSMutableArray??

Comment: yes, sorry i should mention it, i will edit it

Comment: are you sure what loginWithTwitterWithEmail returns?

Comment: Show your loginWithTwitterWithEmail method.

Comment: it is returning everything

Comment: check a value returned by a method of `webSharedManager` used.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this :

```
[user addObject:userName];
```

But you should use NSMutableDictionary with the key-value associations.

Like :

```
[user setObject:userName forKey:@"username"];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
NSMutableArray* user ;
user=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[webSharedManager loginWithTwitterWithEmail:userName username:userName first_name:name gender:@"" last_name:@"" name:name id:ids photo:profileImage]];
```

Also check that the method `loginWithTwitterWithEmailis` is returning an Array or null

Comment: write this in answer not in comment

Answer (score 0):

I think that  you are fetching objects from any source or JSON responde. I recommend you to use JSONModel. JSONModel automatically map your data into objects:

```
"json_response": [
   {
     "name": "John",
     "lastname": "Doe"
   },
   {
     "name": "Mike",
     "lastname": "Donovan"
   }
]
```

Map in your object and get array of users:

```
NSArray *users = [User arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:json[@"json_response"]];
```

Check it out: https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel

Answer (score -1):

try like this

NSMutableArray  *recipes;
    recipes =[[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"hello",@"omnamayshivay", nil]];